# Использование hint в java

Tags: java

Есть эдит (JTextField)
Необходимо сделать подсказку для него

Для тех кто не понял:
На сайтах когда проходишь регистрацию и/или вход есть hint (серый текст в эдите)

[image: hint на примере google входа в аккаунт]

Comment: Это может помочь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738966/java-jtextfield-with-input-hint

Comment: это promp text вроде, по крайней мере в FX так.

Comment: А почему Вы не делаете, позвольте поинтересоваться?  Что Вам мешает?

Comment: Незнание кода который нужно писать

Comment: JTextField textFieldA = new HintTextField("A hint here");
JTextField textFieldB = new HintTextField("Another hint here");
не помогает

Comment: проверил, код из первого комментария - работает. что у вас не работает?